# Adding information to MYSQL database using JSP private login

Tags: mysql, jsp, authentication, restriction

So, I am working on a JSP project where I have a user login that pulls information from the MYSQL database.

I have a table called menu which contains menuid, name, info, price and restaurantid.

When I login I am able to see the menuid, name, info and price.

The problem is when I need to add a menu. When I click to add menu I can add name, info, and price, since the menuid is auto increment, but I need to add the restaurantid as well and I dont want it.

What I am trying to do is when I login the restaurantid should be added automatically according to the user that is logged in when a he adds a menu.

How can I do that?

Here is my adding to the database in JSP:

```
    <%
        MenuId = request.getParameter("MenuId");
        Name = request.getParameter("Name");
        Info = request.getParameter("Info");
        Resturants_ResturantID = request.getParameter("Resturants_ResturantID");

        menu_price1 = request.getParameter("Price");
        if (menu_price1 != null || !"".equals(menu_price1))
            Price = Double.parseDouble(menu_price1);


        pstmt = con
                .prepareStatement("Insert into menu(MenuId,Name,Info,Price,Resturants_ResturantID) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, MenuId);
        pstmt.setString(2, Name);
        pstmt.setString(3, Info);
        pstmt.setDouble(4, Price);
        pstmt.setString(5, Resturants_ResturantID);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        con.close();
        session.setAttribute("menu", "Menu added successfully");
        response.sendRedirect("add_menu.jsp");
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the restaurantId of the logged in user into the user session and add it into your insert statement when you add a menu.

Comment: How can I create this session?

Comment: looks to me you already use the session in your jsp snippet above since you do 
`session.setAttribute("menu", "Menu added successfully");`.  You can add the restaurant id also I guess:
`session.setAttribute("Resturants_ResturantID", Resturants_ResturantID);`